# Get active flags on Android Window

Tags: android, window, flags, window-managers

is it possible to get programmatically which flags are currently active on a Window?

We can enable flags with:

> ```
> getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
> ```

Does api provides a way to get a list of currently active flags? 
Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use:

```
int flags = getWindow().getAttributes().flags;
```

You can see it's used by the `Window.setFlags()` implementation:

```
public void setFlags(int flags, int mask) {
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getAttributes();
    attrs.flags = (attrs.flags&~mask) | (flags&mask);
    ...
```

To determine if individual flags are set, you must use bitwise and. For example:

```
if ((flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION) != 0) ...
```

Comment: yeah but it return me an int that doen't concern nthing... :S

Comment: @iGio90 the int contains all your flags. you just need bitwise operation to extract them. Edited the answer, check the example.